# Find the rule of the following function: $g + 3jx$

Tags: linear-algebra

The domain of f and g is $X := \subseteq \{a,b\} \mathbb{R}$

$f(a) = 1$

$f(b) = 3$

$g(a) = 2$

$g(b) = -1$

Find the rule of $g + 3jx$. (note: the values of a, b and j are unknown)

What I did was 
$$(g + 3jx) (a) = g(a) + 3j(a)$$
and 
$$(g + 3jx) (b) = g(b) + 3j(b)$$

My teacher did pretty much the same but removed the j from the answers. I admit I was a bit distracted and was too shy to ask. Why did he remove the j?

Comment: What's with the $f$ function? Is it somehow related to the problem?

Comment: @Andrei Oh. It's used in other exercises. This isn't the only question in this exercise. It's not relevant to this one I think.